# how to reset mac local host name to defaults

Tags: high-sierra, preferences

So I was messing around with Sharing Preferences and I accidentally changed the name of the local host name I don't remember the previous name so I would like to reset it back to what it was before and I also have a full time machine backup.

Comment: The name doesn't matter very much, is there a special need for turning it back to the original name?

Comment: Well I actually like the original name because it was very long and I liked it. But anyways I found out the original name by just opening my Time machine backup disk and then open backup.backupdb and there will be folder with the name of my local host name I don't know how!

Comment: Yeah, looking in Backups.backup should work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any admin account:

- Open Terminal
- Run `sudo gzcat /var/log/system.log.7.gz | head` (admin password required)
- The name as of seven days ago will be shown at the beginning of each line right after date/time.

Answer (score 1):

From your Time Machine backup, open

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

Take a look at the System:Network:HostNames:LocalHostName and System:System:ComputerName keys for the host name and computer name set at that time.

[image]